# Php & html guessing machine. This is the code , what possibly would be wrong?

Tags: php, html

Guessing machine that asks for two even numbers to find the odd number between them, but its not working, what would be wrong?

```
<?php
$num_to_guess = 17;
if(!isset(($_POST['guess']) && ($_POST['guess1']))){
$message="Try to guess an odd number by entering the two even numbers directly before and after it";}
elseif (($_POST['guess'] < $num_to_guess) && ($_POST['guess1'] > $num_to_guess)){
$message="You guessed the odd number 17";}  
elseif (($_POST['guess'] < $num_to_guess) && ($_POST['guess1'] <$num_to_guess)){
$message="Both numbers you entered are smaller than the odd number";}
elseif (($_POST['guess'] > $num_to_guess) && ($_POST ['guess1'] > $num_to_guess)){
$message="Both numbers you entered are larger than the odd number";}
elseif (($_POST['guess']%2!=0) && ($_POST['guess1']%2!=0)){
$message="Please enter even numbers only";}     
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>A PHP number guessing script</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<p><label for="guess">Welcome! Enter your new guesses:</label><br/>
<input type="text" is="guess" name="guess" />
<input type="text" is="guess1" name="guess1"/></p>
<button type="guess" name="guess" value="guess">guess</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have define conditions in isset(), which is wrong. Instead of '&&', use ',' (comma sign). i.e.

```
if(!isset($_POST['guess'], $_POST['guess1'])){
   // your code here
}
```